# html5 and webservices versus mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, html

At my company we have a discussion as to in what way our future web applications should be build. We currently have 2 groups of developers who agree on several things. We all want to use html5 and css3 and jQuery. We mostly agree that web services will be very important.

However, one group advocates the use of mvc because it would add more structure? to the project. The other half (to which I admit I belong to), sees no reason not to consume the webservices directly from the client, forgoing mvc controller views etc.

To me adding mvc will only add another performance burden on the server that could be shifted to the client and structure could also be added to non mvc projects, though it might ask a little more effort from the developers.

At the risk of starting a flamewar. I would like to hear some arguments for either side from outside the company.

Comment: Why this debate? Each client page will do its own work (yes, I guess you want to keep logic separated by topic!) and server will do its own. A web service needs to provide just data? Consume by client. Data used to build a page? Consume by server (anyway there's not a rule, just common sense).

Comment: How will you display the data to the client.  Surely you need to have some sort of client, whether it be ASP>NET MVC or web forms, Windows app, etc.  Each of these would need to consume the service.  I like MVC3 because it's structure and the many benefits of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You are having the wrong discussion. HTML5, CSS and Javascript (and JQuery) are client side technologies. ASP.NET MVC is a server side technology. You still need code on the server that sends and retrieves data from the database. The next version of MVC (4, beta) will have Web API which is an excellent solution to create those webservices with.